# how to use a single jquery to change a div's display property and animate

Tags: jquery, html

I was making a page where i clicked a button and a full menu opens using the jquery animate command. Then when you click the cross picture, it closes again with the animate command. But the problem is that it's position is fixed and it contains numbers from 1-30. so when you hide the div, it hides but the numbers are still visible on the left side until or unless you have not changed it's display property to none

```
//this resets the size of div to 0
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#fullmenu").animate({
  height:'0%',
  width:'0%'
  });
  });
  //This opens the div
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#imgdot").click(function(){
  $("#fullmenu").animate({
height:'90%',
width:'90%',
    });
  });
});
 //This closes the div when the image cross is clicked
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#cross").click(function(){
    $("#fullmenu").animate({
            height:'0%',
            width:'0%'
      });
   });
});
```

My question is how to change the display property to none and also animate the div at the same time is a single function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuerys animations often don't affect children of a div,

you can try this:

```
$("#fullmenu").animate({
        height:'0%',
        width:'0%'
}).children().hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$('#foo').fadeOut("slow", function(){
    var div = $("<div id='foo'>test2</div>").hide();
    $(this).replaceWith(div);
    $('#foo').fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Css can be changed as $("#divId").css('display','none');

$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#cross").click(function(){

    $("#fullmenu").animate({

            height:'0%',
            width:'0%'
      },complete:function(){

$("#fullmenu").css('display','none')
});
   });
});


That said, you could use :

$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#cross").click(function(){

    $("#fullmenu").slideUp();
   });
```

Comment: When i write your code, the whole  jquery file would not work. I do not want it to slide or hide or fade etc. I just want to animate it so that when you close it, it get's the shrink effect

Comment: Try this: $("#fullmenu").animate({height:'0%',
 width:'0%'
}, 5000, function() {  $("#fullmenu").css('display','none')
// Animation complete.
});

Comment: Do you mean: `$(document).ready(function(){ //enter
  $("#cross").click(function(){ //enter
    $("#fullmenu").animate({height:'0%', width:'0%' }, 5000,  //enterfunction(){ //enter
      $("#fullmenu").css('display','none')  //enter
      }); //enter
    }); //enter
  }); //enter
});

Comment: No it still won't run. The whole file won't run. Do you want me to give you the atachments

Comment: Could you please create a fiddle. I think that would be helpful.

Comment: what's a fiddle. I am new to stackoverflow

Comment: Fiddle is a site where you can create/test your javascript code: this link shows your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/WBNAJ/3/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WBNAJ/22/. But this also does not work properly. the position:fixed; part is not working and the height is not set to 90%